# LiveData's Transformations.map not being triggered in, and only in, Unit Tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-livedata

I have a ViewModel like this one:

```kotlin
class MyViewModel {
    val title = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val onTitleError: LiveData<Int?> = Transformations.map(title, this::validateTitle)
}
```

The problem is when executing during Unit Tests `Transformations.map` is never triggered by a `title` value change. As example:

```kotlin
val viewModel = MyViewModel()
viewModel.title.value = "123"

Assert.assertEquals(viewModel.onTitleError.value, R.string.myError)
```

I'm using this rule for LiveData tests:

```kotlin
@Rule
var liveDataRule: TestRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

When executing during Instrumented Tests, or normal running, everything works just fine.

Just exemplifying @ianhanniballake answer, i just added `viewModel.onTitleError.observeForever { }`, then above snippet should look like this:

```kotlin
val viewModel = MyViewModel()

viewModel.onTitleError.observeForever { }
viewModel.title.value = "123"

Assert.assertEquals(viewModel.onTitleError.value, R.string.myError)
```

Comment: Where you do observe your `onTitleError`?

Comment: FWIW, I am a fan of [`livedata-testing`](https://github.com/jraska/livedata-testing). It offers a `TestObserver` that not only handles your `observeForever()` bit but also adds a bunch of assertions about what the observer has seen.

Comment: Really nice lib, @CommonsWare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `observe` your `onTitleError` LiveData to have it populate its `value`.